# Algorithms to find difference/similarity in a sequence of images/frames

Tags: algorithm, opencv, computer-vision

I am searching for known algorithms (perhaps openCV function) that can output similarity or difference in a given specified number of sequence of images/frames (say 2 or 10).

Journal/conference article is also appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: strongly depends on your definition of "similarity" which is very domain dependend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform it using **Structural Similarity Index**

For related publication check out the paper titled ***Image Quality Assessment: From Error Visibility to
Structural Similarity*** by Zou Wang in IEEE TRANSACTIONS ON IMAGE PROCESSING

There isn't any function available in OpenCV (as far as I can remember), though there si one in scikit_image. It is the `ssim` module made available by this line `from skimage.measure import structural_similarity as ssim`.

The good thing about ssim is it considers:

- the **mean** of pixel intensities for within a given window.
- the **variance** of the pixel intensities
- and the **covariance**

The formula given in equation 13 of the linked paper contains the above three.

A sample implementation is provided [HERE](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/transform/plot_ssim.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer :-)

Comment: Indeed, one that I was hunting for :-)