# Find images with similar content to the source image on python

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, pydicom

I'm working on a subject that identifies areas of cerebral hemorrhage and there is a problem like this:

I use the tensorflow library to format the cerebral hemorrhage, then save it as a png file. Now I want to find images of cerebral hemorrhage like a source image, how can I do this?

Thank you very much, wish everyone a wonderful day.

Comment: Your training set is just 1 image ?

Comment: No, There are about 200 pictures in my training set

Comment: @Tr have a look at [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50170678/algorithms-to-find-difference-similarity-in-a-sequence-of-images-frames/50188572#50188572) to see if it suits your requirement!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer